# working with sorting array_chunk

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to generate a table of years that is split into groups of 5 years each. i would like it to be sort 5 years each like in the example desired output ...This is what I got so far.

```
    <?php
  $chunkSize = 5;
  $starting_year  = 2006;
  $ending_year    = date("Y");
  //create an array of years
  $years = range($ending_year,$starting_year); 
  //[2006,2007,....,2016,2017]

  //split years in required size
  $chunked = array_chunk($years,$chunkSize);
  //[ [2013,....,2017], [2008,...2012], [2006,2007]]



  echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'><tbody>";
  foreach($chunked as $chunk) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($chunk as $year) {
      echo "<th>{$year}</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    foreach($chunk as $year) {

      echo "<td>test</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Current Output

```
2017    2016    2015    2014    2013
test    test    test    test    test
2012    2011    2010    2009    2008
test    test    test    test    test
2007    2006
test    test
```

Desired Output

```
2013    2014    2015    2016    2017
test    test    test    test    test
2008    2009    2010    2011    2012
test    test    test    test    test
2006    2007
test    test
```

edit:

i tried

```
<?php
  $chunkSize = 5;
  $starting_year  = 2006;
  $ending_year    = date("Y");
  //create an array of years
  $years = range($ending_year,$starting_year); 
  //[2006,2007,....,2016,2017]

  //split years in required size
  $chunked = array_chunk($years,$chunkSize);
  //[ [2013,....,2017], [2008,...2012], [2006,2007]]


  //reverse it
  $reversed = array_reverse($chunked); 


  echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'><tbody>";
  foreach($reversed as $reverse) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($reverse as $year) {
      echo "<th>{$year}</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    foreach($reverse as $year) {

      echo "<td>test</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</tbody></table>";
```

output

```
2007    2006
test    test
2012    2011    2010    2009    2008
test    test    test    test    test
2017    2016    2015    2014    2013
test    test    test    test    test
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to reverse the order of the years. Use `array_reverse` on the chunks.

Comment: i updated my question..i tried array_reverse but i got different output

Comment: Do `array_reverse` on each chunk, not on the array of chunks.

Comment: Right after the first foreach.  `foreach ($chunked as $chunk) { $chunk = array_reverse($chunk);`

Comment: Thank you..got it

Comment: Don't reverse the list of chunks. Either generate the years in ascending order and reverse the list of chunks or let the years generation as it is now and reverse each chunk before printing.

Answer (score 1):

Not that this way is any better necessarily, but just FYI you can do this without any arrays or chunking or reversing. Starting with your initially defined values:

```
$chunkSize = 5;
$starting_year  = 2006;
$ending_year    = date("Y");
```

Determine how many rows you'll need

```
$rows = ceil(($ending_year - $starting_year) / $chunkSize);
```

Then iterate for that number of rows with a for loop.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {

    // determine the starting year for the current row
    $start = max($starting_year, $ending_year - $chunkSize + 1);

    // output the th and td rows for each row
    for ($td = 0; $td < 2; $td++) {

        // output the years  and 'test' values for the current row
        echo '<tr>';
        for ($year = $start; $year <= $ending_year; $year++) {
            echo  $td ? '<td>test</td>' : "<th>$year</th>";
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    // decrement the ending year for the next iteration
    $ending_year -= $chunkSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
  $chunkSize = 5;
  $starting_year  = 2006;
  $ending_year    = date("Y");
  //create an array of years
  $years = range($ending_year,$starting_year); 
  //[2006,2007,....,2016,2017]

  //split years in required size
  $chunked = array_chunk($years,$chunkSize);
  //[ [2013,....,2017], [2008,...2012], [2006,2007]]



  echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'><tbody>";
  foreach($chunked as $chunk) {
 $chunk = array_reverse($chunk);
    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($chunk as $year) {

      echo "<th>{$year}</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    foreach($chunk as $year) {

      echo "<td>test</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</tbody></table>";
```